# php, how to clone DOMElement?

Tags: php, dom, clone, domdocument

Official documentation says that DOMElement has inherited method cloneNode http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php  . If i try to clone, it does not work. How to copy element from one DOMDocument to another? Namely, i have misplaced head, thus i have somehow to copy head and body, and than to echo them in right order.

```
ob_start();
$viewData = $this->data; 
include_once( $this->viewTemplPath.$this->file );
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($buffer);

$head = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
print_r('<br><br> 184 view.php head='); var_dump($head); 

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
print_r('<br><br> 188 view.php body='); var_dump($body); 

$docNew = new \DOMDocument();
$headNew = $head->cloneNone(true); // Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::cloneNone()
$docNew->appendChild($headNew);
$bodyNew = $body->cloneNone(true); // Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::cloneNone()
$docNew->appendChild($bodyNew);

echo $docNew->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `cloneNode()` instead of `cloneNone()`

Comment: maybe `->cloneNode` ? not the `cloneNone`

Comment: Also I suggest you to use some IDE to prevent errors like this :)

Comment: what do you mean by IDE?

Comment: That's what I call a Freudian typo!

Comment: _“Namely, i have misplaced head, thus i have somehow to copy head and body, and than to echo them in right order”_ - so you are trying to fix the output of a messed up template via DOM afterwards? Would it not be more effective to fix the template …?

Answer (score 1):

In order to clone the Element, the solution is to import the Element i want to clone to the Document, and than add it as a child : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php
This does not through errors, and echoes the new document.
But this does not resolve the problem with misplaced head.

```
ob_start();
$viewData = $this->data; 
include_once( $this->viewTemplPath.$this->file );
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($buffer);
$head = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$docNew = new \DOMDocument();
$headNew = $docNew->importNode($head, true); 
$docNew->appendChild($headNew);
$bodyNew = $docNew->importNode($body, true); 
$docNew->appendChild($bodyNew);

echo $docNew->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo mistake,
you wrote it `CloneNone(true)`,
it should be `cloneNode(true)`